# Invalid top-level type in JSON write in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, afnetworking, nsjsonserialization

i'm trying to do a PUT using AFNetworking. I need to send an array of participants in a competition, but i'm getting the "Invalid top-level type in JSON write in Swift" error. The JSON I generate is perfect, and if I try it using REST Client everything works. Here's my code:

```
func sendUsers(onComplete: (NSError?) -> Void) {
    var error: NSError?
    var jsonData: NSData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self.createDictionaryOfParticipations(), options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: &error)!
    var jsonString: String = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    println("Json: \(jsonString)")
    if self.requestManager == nil {
        self.requestManager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager();
    }
    self.requestManager?.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer();
    let requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
    self.requestManager?.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;
    self.requestManager?.requestSerializer.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type");
    self.requestManager?.PUT(kParticipantsUrl, parameters: jsonString, success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, object: AnyObject!) -> Void in
        self.persistUsers([])
        onComplete(nil)
        }, failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            onComplete(error)
    })
}
```

And the method within I create the JSONObject:

```
func createDictionaryOfParticipations() -> NSArray {
    var dict: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    var participants: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var savedParticipants: [User] = self.getUsers() as [User]
    for participant: User in savedParticipants {
        var participantDict: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
        participantDict.setValue(participant.name, forKey: kNameKey)
        participantDict.setValue(participant.firstSurname, forKey: kFirstSurnameKey)
        participantDict.setValue(participant.secondSurname, forKey: kSecondSurnameKey)
        participantDict.setValue(participant.dni, forKey: kDniKey)
        participantDict.setValue(participant.address, forKey: kAddressKey)
        participantDict.setValue(participant.postalCode, forKey: kPostalCodeKey)
        participantDict.setValue(participant.city, forKey: kCityKey)
        participantDict.setValue(participant.province, forKey: kProvinceKey)
        participantDict.setValue(participant.phone, forKey: kPhoneKey)
        participantDict.setValue(participant.email, forKey: kEmailKey)
        participantDict.setValue(participant.code, forKey: kCodeKey)
        participantDict.setValue(participant.prize, forKey: kPrizeKey)
        participants.addObject(participantDict)
    }
    return participants
}
```

If I run the app and send the request, I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103b5df35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001037f6bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103b5de6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   Foundation                          0x000000010349b0ea +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:] + 264
4   MLB                                 0x00000001031cb23c -[AFJSONRequestSerializer requestBySerializingRequest:withParameters:error:] + 1164
5   MLB                                 0x00000001031c13bd -[AFHTTPRequestSerializer requestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:error:] + 1869
6   MLB                                 0x00000001031e6d14 -[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager PUT:parameters:success:failure:] + 388
7   MLB                                 0x000000010317acf0 _TFC3MLB12UsersManager9sendUsersfS0_FFGSqCSo7NSError_T_T_ + 8656
8   MLB                                 0x0000000103166426 _TFC3MLB22MainMenuViewController9alertViewfS0_FTCSo11UIAlertView20clickedButtonAtIndexSi_T_ + 630
9   MLB                                 0x0000000103166602 _TToFC3MLB22MainMenuViewController9alertViewfS0_FTCSo11UIAlertView20clickedButtonAtIndexSi_T_ + 66
10  UIKit                               0x00000001046773e0 -[UIAlertView _prepareToDismissForTappedIndex:] + 161
11  UIKit                               0x0000000104676ede __35-[UIAlertView _prepareAlertActions]_block_invoke50 + 43
12  UIKit                               0x0000000104670464 -[UIAlertController _dismissAnimated:triggeringAction:triggeredByPopoverDimmingView:] + 89
13  UIKit                               0x00000001047c6540 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 9487
14  UIKit                               0x000000010445eff6 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1041
15  UIKit                               0x000000010445fc23 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 667
16  UIKit                               0x000000010442c9b1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
17  UIKit                               0x0000000104439a7d _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370
18  UIKit                               0x0000000104415103 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103a93551 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103a8941d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103a88a54 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103a88486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
23  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001084ca9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
24  UIKit                               0x0000000104418420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
25  MLB                                 0x000000010319f84e top_level_code + 78
26  MLB                                 0x000000010319f88a main + 42
27  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010679c145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I don't know where's the problem... the object which properties I put into the JSON is a NSObject and all the fields I put into the json are Strings (String type, not NSString) and I've tried to used NSString but I still get the error. Any ideas?? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the JSON serialisation yourself, and then asking AFN to do it again, so you're passing an `NSString` and asking it to be serialised to JSON, which won't work.

What you should be doing is passing the `NSArray` returned from `createDictionaryOfParticipations` instead:

```
self.requestManager?.PUT(kParticipantsUrl, parameters: self.createDictionaryOfParticipations(), success:...
```

Comment: Cool, but now I get this error:
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7fdee3753d10 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: Where's the stack trace? It seems you are asking about help with basic debugging here.

Comment: Ok now it is completely solved, the last erro was because the webservice wasn't returning anything, now it returns a "success" and everything works fine. Thanks Wain!