# Crashes on AFNetworking POST

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to post json string as NSString. However on post request Xcode crashes and prints: "Invalid top-level type in JSON write". Here is my code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];


[manager POST:signupBaseURLString parameters:myJSONStringObject success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"responseObject is %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"post request error is %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: is your jsonstring object valid ?

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27166711/invalid-top-level-type-in-json-write-in-swift

Comment: how do you create myJsonStringObject. You shouldn't have to make it a string, as the request serializer does that for you.

Comment: My json(as dictionary) is a valid json object. However, of course myJSONStringObject is not a valid json because it is NSString format.

Comment: Server, i'm sending data, is expecting json as a string format, that is why i am using string as parameter. Can you help me about sending NSString to the server? Request serializer is not seem to make it a string, or i'm doing sth wrong, please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are supposed to be an NSDictionary, not a string.  I assume `myJSONStringObject` is a string.  If the string is the encoding of a JSON object, you need to turn it back into a dictionary, or preferably, use the dictionary that you encoded.

Comment: Yes, it is string, because i need to send it with string format.

Comment: `parameters` needs to be an NSDictionary, not a string. Read the docs: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.html#//api/name/POST:parameters:success:failure: